# Light fixture with no mounting bracket

Tags: grounding

I'm changing a light fixture that has no mounting bracket and the ground runs to a nut and bolt. The old light fixture bracket won't work cause the new light fixture won't cover it up. Where do I attach that ground nut and bolt?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the fixture and the box that's going to feed it?

Comment: Yes, can you provide photos please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Consider this, if have the same issue and asked you the same question as written, would you be able to answer me?